# what is ALT + v

Tags: iphone, xcode

in IOS when you push "Alt + v" it makes a check mark. Does anyone have any idea for the purpose of this character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it's actually a square root (radical) sign, used for quickly inlining simple math formulas.

Comment: That's what it is on OS X (Option-V) as well.